# Proving product space $U \times W_1$ isomorphics to $U \times W_2$ implies $W_1$ is isomorphics to $W_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $U$ is a subspace of $V$, $W_1, W_2$ are two arbitrary finite-dimensional vector spaces.
I'm doing a problem on Linear Algebra, and was trying to do it on a shorter way, mid way, I have come to this problem which I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless $U$ is finite-dimensional, this claim is clearly false.  The following conditions are sufficient for $W_1$ to be isomorphic to $W_2$: (1) $U$ is finite-dimensional or (2) both $W_1$ and $W_2$ are of dimensions greater than or equal to the dimension of $U$.

Comment: What if there is another given condition that both $W_1$ and $W_2$ are finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $U$ has an infinite dimension $c$ over the base field $K$.  Let $B$ be a basis of $U$.  For any two vector spaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of dimensions $c_1$ and $c_2$, respectively, over $K$ with $c_1,c_2\leq c$, let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be bases of $W_1$ and $W_2$, respectively.  Then, $B'_i:=\big(B\times \{0\}\big)\cup\big(\{0\}\times B_i\big)$ is a basis for $U\times W_i$ with cardinality $c+c_i=c$, for $i=1,2$.  Thus, there exists a bijection $f_i:B\to B_i'$.  This bijective function $f_i$ can be extended linearly to obtain an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces $\varphi_i:U\to U\times W_i$.  Thus,
$$U\times W_1 \cong U \cong U\times W_2\,.$$
Since we can choose two unequal (possibly finite) cardinalities $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1,c_2\leq c$, the claim is false.

Suppose $U$, $W_1$, and $W_2$ are such that $U\times W_1\cong U\times W_2$.  For infinite $c$, this argument also shows why $c_1\geq c$ and $c_2\geq c$ imply that $W_1\cong W_2$.  This is because $c+c_1=c_1$ and $c+c_2=c_2$.  For finite $c$ and finite $c_1$, we have $c_2\leq c+c_2=c+c_1<\infty$, so $c_2$ is also finite.  Similarly, for finite $c$ and finite $c_2$, $c_1$ is also finite.  For finite $c$, $c_1$, and $c_2$, we have $c+c_1=c+c_2$ implies $c_1=c_2$.  For finite $c$, $c_1$, and $c_2$, we have $c+c_1=c+c_2$ implies $c_1=c_2$.  For finite $c$, but infinite $c_1$ and $c_2$, we have $c_1=c+c_1=c+c_2=c_2$.  Hence, if $U$ is finite-dimensional or if both $\dim_K(W_1)$ and $\dim_K(W_2)$ are greater than or equal to $\dim_K(U)$, then $W_1\cong W_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two very basic key facts on vector spaces:

1. Vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.
2. The dimension of a product of vector spaces is the sum of the dimensions of the summands.

Set $u:=\dim U$ and $w_i:=\dim W_i$ for $i=1,2$. By point 2 we have $\dim U\times W_i=u+w_i$. Given that $U\times W_1\cong U\times W_2$, it follows from point 1 that that $u+w_1=u+w_2$. If $u$, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are finite it follows that $w_1=w_2$. Then it follows from point 1 again that $W_1\cong W_2$.